# Polymorphism: is this (potentially intensive) use of static_cast a fatality?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, static-cast

Here is the context: A `Model` has a (pointer to) `Parameter` and an `output`. `Model` and `Parameter` are abstract classes. We use pointers of type `Model*` to manipulate various derived (concrete) classes of `Model`, whose pointers to `Parameter` dynamically point to instances of various derived (concrete) classes of `Parameter`.

Here is a simplified version of the classes as an example. I know `new` should be avoided or at least followed by `delete`, but I omitted off-topic lines of code (such as destructors).

```
// Abstract classes
class Parameter {
public:
    virtual void reinitialize() = 0;
};

class Model{
public:
    Model(Parameter *argt){ ptr_param = argt; }
    virtual void computeModelOutput() = 0;
    double output;
    Parameter *ptr_param;
};

// Concrete classes
class ACertainKindOfParameter : public Parameter{
public:
    ACertainKindOfParameter(int argt){ value = argt; }
    virtual void reinitialize(){ value = 1; }
    int value;
};

class ACertainKindOfModel : public Model{
public:
    ACertainKindOfModel(int argt) : Model(new ACertainKindOfParameter(argt)){}
    virtual void computeModelOutput(){
        output = 10.0 + (double)(static_cast<ACertainKindOfParameter*>(ptr_param)->value);
    }
};

int main(){
    ACertainKindOfModel myModel{5};
    Model *ptr_model = &myModel;
    ptr_model->computeModelOutput();
    std::cout << ptr_model->output << std::endl; // 15
}
```

What bothers me in this code is that `ACertainKindOfModel` has no direct access to `value`, so I apparently need to use `static_cast`. A real `Model` would of course have a vector of e.g. 50 `Parameter`s, not just one, so that would mean 50 `static_cast` each time the `output` is computed (or any other action relying on parameters). That does not look like a good practice to me, but I may be wrong. Do you see any flaw in the design?

Note: I thought of making `Parameter` a class template, but it doesn't seem to be a valid option because the methods of `Parameter` differ deeply when different types of `value` are considered. In the simple example above, `value` is of type `int`, but in another class derived from `Parameter` it could be of user-defined type, e.g. `Color` with only three possible values `R`, `G` and `B`, and `reinitialize()` would be very different than `value = 1`. A virtual `getter()` in `Parameter` would be great but would not work either, because of a conflicting return type in the redefinition.

Comment: What are you going to do with value? If it's computation, look into the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) so no other class has to know what the value is. If it's display, consider adding a virtual getter that returns the value in a neutral form like a `string`.

Comment: @user4581301 Indeed, `value` is mainly for computation as shown in the piece of code I wrote, and it could also appear in conditions such as `if(value == R)`, etc. (especially where `value` is not a number). Thank you for your advice about the Visitor pattern.

Comment: *"I know new should be avoided"*. So use smart pointers: and even less line of code.

Comment: No need to use `dynamic_cast` when you're absolutely sure of the static type of the pointer, `static_cast` will work just as well and be less overhead.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yes you are right, so I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: That changes the question completely. `dynamic_cast` involves a certain amount of overhead, but `static_cast` is generally done completely at compile time so there's no overhead at all. Now the only concern becomes the verbosity of the code.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I have another concern though, about the general design of the code. Surely, I described a very common situation in OOP, but in my (small indeed) experience I never heard of cast as a kind of inevitable "collateral damage" from polymorphism. If nobody on this site sees anything wrong with it, then I'll accept the `static_cast` solution.

Comment: I see reinitialize and no use of it.  I see arguments passed in, stored in parent where their type is forgotten, then retrieved in the child.  The storing in the parent seems pointless; if stored in the child the type would never be forgotten and no problem would exist.  So stop converting them to parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several approaches to make this cleaner.  If `Model` does not need access to `ptr_param`, you could remove that from `Model` and store it within each derived class, with the correct type.

Or you can encapsulate the `static_cast` in a getter function within each model class:

```
ACertainKindOfParameter *getParam() const { return static_cast<ACertainKindOfParameter *>(ptr_param); }
```

You can combine the two techniques.  Define the parameter within the derived model class, and use a covariant return type to allow the base `Model` class access.  Within `Model`, declare a getter:

```
virtual Parameter *getParam() const = 0;
```

Then, within each model, declare a covariant override:

```
virtual ACertainKindOfParameter *getParam() const override { return ptr_param; }
```

which assumes ptr_param is declared within `ACertainKindOfModel`.  If it isn't you'll need to apply the `static_cast` as above.

Or you can save the result of the `static_cast` within the `compute` function to avoid having to use it multiple times.

Comment: My personal conclusion: I tried countless things and it mainly boils down to the initial `static_cast`.  Making `Parameter` a template class almost worked but ultimately failed because template argument deduction [does not work for declaring pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085683/).