# Template argument deduction for class templates in C++17: am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++17

According to
https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html, version 7 of g++, used with flag `-std=c++1z`, supports template argument deduction for class templates.

I would expect the following code to compile, especially as `Base` is an abstract class, therefore:
1. the compiler knows no instance of `Base` can be created;
2. the pointer to base `pt_base` points to a clearly defined instance (i.e. `Derived<int>{42}`) where the type (`int`) is explicit.

```
template<typename ValueType>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ValueType getValue() = 0;
};

template<typename ValueType>
class Derived : public Base<ValueType>{
public:
    Derived(ValueType argt){ value = argt; }
    virtual ValueType getValue(){ return value; }
    ValueType value;
};

int main(){
    Base *pt_base = new(Derived<int>{42}); // *ERROR*
    delete pt_base;
}
```

Yet, it [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96b3b15825ccad7e). G++ complains that "*template placeholder type 'Base' must be followed by a simple declarator-id*"; if I understand correctly, it does not deduce the template argument.
It's a pity because I would like to dynamically decide which derived class `pt_base` points to (could be an object from class `Derived<someType>` or from class `Derived2<someType2>`). That way, an array or a `vector<Base *>` could store pointers to objects of various derived classes.

GCC only has [experimental support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) for C++17 and I don't have access to another compiler, so although I get a compile error I am not sure my code is wrong. What do you think?
And how could we dynamically decide that `pt_base` points to an object from either `Derived<someType>` or `Derived2<someType2>` (so polymorphism can be used)?

Comment: That error message claims that the `*` in `Base *pt_base` is not allowed.  `*pt_base` is a _declarator_, but is not a _declarator-id_ (such as an undecorated identifier).  I can't find this rule anywhere in N4687, though.

Comment: @aschepler The rules for deduction just only kick in in certain spots. And the [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) explicitly ruled out things like pointers, functions, and references.

Comment: Also, template class deduction happens at compile time. In the situations where you *are* allowed to write just `Base`, the compiler will decide whether it actually means `Base<someType>` or whatever.  `Base` is not a type.  So you can't have a single variable point at either a `Derived<someType>` or `Derived<someType2>` at runtime, unless they actually both inherit some common type.  You might need a `std::any` or `std::variant` for the return type of its `getValue()`.

Comment: If `vector<Base*>` was valid, type erasure would be supported by the language directly ...

Comment: @Barry [dcl.type.class.deduct] "If a placeholder for a deduced class type appears as a _decl-specifier_ in the _decl-specifier-seq_ of an initializing declaration of a variable, the placeholder is replaced by the return type of the function selected by overload resolution for class template deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])."  By the letter, that sentence would apply.  Though in this example it would fail because none of the invented constructors for `Base` can accept a pointer.  But by a strict reading, I think `std::vector&& v(1,1);` might be allowed.  Seems like a Defect to me.

Comment: @Barry That paper's easily the poorest written adopted paper I've ever read. But then, I'm not really a fan of this whole "feature".

Comment: @aschepler [P0620](https://wg21.link/P0620) removed the original restriction, apparently unintentionally (the goal for that edit was to remove the requirement for an initializer, if I understand correctly). I guess that's what you get for a feature that got reworked and patched until the very last second :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class template argument deduction works for declaring instances of class types:

```
Derived d(42);
```

Or new-expressions:

```
auto p = new Derived(42);
```

Or function-style casts:

```
foo(Derived(42));
```

It does not work for declaring pointers.

---

You'll have to simply provide the template arguments as you've always had to. Or, I guess:

```
template <class T> Base<T>* downcast(Base<T>* p) { return p; }
auto pt_base = downcast(new Derived(42));
```