# How to change the type/typedef of a class member dynamicly?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef

Follwing Problem. I am working on a bigger c++ project. That project has a central dataClass: `mal::FrameAudio` and the data class looks like this:

```
class FrameAudio  {
 public:

  typedef Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> pluginType;
...
const pluginType& getPlug() const;
void setPlug(const pluginType& plugin);
...
```

Now I want to extend some functionality of the software, which needs a different `pluginType` in my case I would need:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> pluginType;
```

**How can I implement the new dataType without breaking the functionality of the rest of the code?**

1. Inheritance? I thought about doing something like this FrameAudioFloat: public FrameAudio. But the data storage get initialized way earlier in the software, outside of my functionality and as far as I know, when a pointer is set to the base class you can only use the overwritten functions of the derived class. So I cannot call getPlug() since it has another return type.
2. Template? I was thinking about creating a template class? But than I saw that the code often uses the typedef of the datastorage. You will find something like this very often in the code:

   `const mal::FrameAudio::pluginType& plugins = aFrame.getPlug();`

I even found that typedef in member definitions of other classes. So what is the easiest way for me to extend this class with the new typedef and funcions? For now its sufficient to me if just my functionality works with the new typedef and the rest of the code still works with the old. Maybe use auto as a typedef?

Comment: may I ask what's the origin question? (for *Follwing Problem*)

Comment: Maybe [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is an option, although not before C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the type of an object dynamically, C++ doesn't allow that. So much up front.

Now, using a template is probably the right way to go. Point is, you probably can not change this while keeping the code the same, which is what you're effectively asking for. Instead, you can write similar code but with the `unsigned char` replaced with a `float`, because that doesn't touch the existing code. In order to avoid actual code duplication, creating a template is the way to go:

```
template <typename scalar> class FrameAudioT
{
    // type from the outer class used in the plugin type
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> pluginType;
    // ...other code...
};
// for compatibility with existing code:
typedef FrameAudioT<char> FrameAudio;
```

Start like that with the `FrameAudio` class. Then, pick the next class which still depends on the legacy, non-templace `FrameAudio` type. Once this type isn't used any more, you can remove the typedef.

Of course, in the middle you can refactor the code. For example, if you find your code only uses a subset of the plugin's interface that doesn't depend on its first parameter, you might be able to create a pure virtual baseclass ("interface class") and use that instead. The details depend on your application, so it's hard to give definite advise.

Comment: Wow Thats a good idea especially with the typedef! So now for example if I have another class DataStorage which has FrameAudio as a class member, I basically do the same: DataStorageT .. And when the typedef is called somewehere like this: 'const mal::FrameAudio::pluginType' I would need to change it to const mal::FrameAudio<float>::pluginType for the new case?

Comment: And one last question. I think that is what you meant at the end. There are Some functions, that are independent from this typedef and it related questions. something like void do(const mal::FrameAudio& frame), do I need to change anything here? Is the FrameAudio<char> and FrameAudio<float> still recognized as a FrameAudio for the function?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. If any of the above "...other code..." does not depend (even indirectly) on the scalar type, you could move that to a non-template baseclass, from which you derive the template class above.

Comment: That is what I started doing, I think thats a really good idea! Now after finalizing my thoughts and planning. I was wondering Why exactly  the template class compared to deriving two classes. I think the typedef FrameAudio trick will still work with derived classes. Isnt the template approach basically the same as the inheritance with the only difference I can only keep the same functions? And also the changes would be the same, for templates I have to declare FrameAudio<float>, for class FrameAudioFloat. So the advantage of template I do not have to copy as much code?

Comment: "the advantage of template I do not have to copy as much code" -- that's it, exactly. You avoid writing separate classes with almost the same code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with templates. You turn your existing code into the base case by defaulting the plugin type to the existing type:

```cpp
template <class PluginType = 
    Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic
>
class FrameAudio  {
 public:

  typedef PluginType pluginType;
...
const pluginType& getPlug() const;
void setPlug(const pluginType& plugin);
};
```

So when `FrameAudio` is used without specifying template arguments it behaves as before, which means existing code and typedefs will all work. Additionally you provide a specialization for the new plugin type:

```cpp
template <>
class FrameAudio<
    Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
>
{
public:
    using PluginType = Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
    // You can even access classes of the base template 
    // if you want to share implementations
    ....
};
```

Another nifty trick is to swap the types behind the curtain, e.g. define

```cpp
using FrameAudio = FrameAudioG<
    Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>
>;
```

where `FrameAudioG` is the generic version with templatized plugin type (as shown above). This way new users utilize the generic interface where both plugins are accessible and legacy code continues to work like before.

Comment: Thanks! I have never seen templates used like this before. In the first code example you are creating a template with a default value. Does that work if you only call FrameAudio, or would I need to change it to FrameAudio<>. Pleas excuse my missing knowldege but what is happening in the second part? what is that using PluginType doing there?

Comment: @Oroshimaru Yes, it works without specifying template arguments in all but one cases; the only case where you need the `<>` is when using a nested typedef (`FrameAudio<>::PluginType`). The `using` is just an alternative syntax for a typedef in this case, it's just easier to read because the new alias is on the left of an assignment operator

Comment: @LorahAttkins adding to your answer I think you also need <> when declaring pointers right? see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46085772/16743536